# CakePHP unable to reach CakeSession from lib

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I added a lib called MyLib, inside my `App/Lib` folder in CakePHP 2.5.5:

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class MyLib {

    public static function myfunction1() {
        return CakeSession::read('Config.language');
    }

    public static function myfunction2() {
        return $_SESSION;
    }

}
```

I defined it inside `App/Config/bootstrap.php`:

```
App::uses('MyLib', 'Lib');
```

Inside MyController1 I use it like this.
myAction gives empty output:
When I check I see that session data is empty for MyController1.

```
class MyController1 {

   function myAction1(){

    echo MyLib::myfunction1();
    print_r(MyLib::myfunction2());

   }
}
```

I also have another controller named MyController2.
When I use `MyLib::myfunction1()` everything works fine for MyController2.

```
class MyController2 {

   function myAction2(){

    echo MyLib::myfunction1();
    print_r(MyLib::myfunction2());

  }
}
```

What would make session to be empty for some controller / action ?

Comment: Where do you write 'Config.language' to session?

Comment: As the result is different between two controllers, could it be the classical problem of a `beforeFilter()` not calling its parent `beforeFilter()` defined in AppController that would do some required stuff in order for your lib to work ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo when loading your library.

```
App::uses('MyLib ', 'Lib');
```

See the blank space after `MyLib`? It should be:

```
App::uses('MyLib', 'Lib');
```

You are also misusing `print_r` function. The second parameter tells the function if you want to return the information rather than print it. You should do:

```
print_r(MyLib::myfunction2());
```

Although you also can do this:

```
$my_session = print_r(MyLib::myfunction2(),true);
echo $my_session;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Thanks. I made typo while copy pasting, but problem isn't a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This is an ugly solution but it helped in my case. Try to add App::uses in method. Something like this:

```
class MyController2 {

   function myAction2(){
    App::uses('MyLib', 'Lib');
    echo MyLib::myfunction1();
    print_r(MyLib::myfunction2());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have a problem elsewhere in your code that you are not showing us (I guess you have shown some example code here that isn't your real code).

I have tested with your exact code and both controllers show exactly the same. There's absolutely no reason why one controller would show something different unless that controller contains something else that the other one doesn't have.